# MariaDB: Receiving error 08000: Socket error

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I am running a webserver on a raspberry pi. When running a query, I am receiving the error "08000: Socket error".

When looking further into details, I realized that this error is occuring when looking for one special row of one table:

```
select *  from my_table where `id` = 12470 => is working fine
select *  from my_table where `id` = 12471 => error 08000: Socket error
select *  from my_table where `id` = 12472 => is working fine
```

Deleting or updating the desired row with id 12471 is also failing.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: That sounds odd. Could you have a corruption in that table

Comment: what happens with `select *  from my_table where `id` IN  (12470,12471,12472)` that will nozthing to do with the id, your rapsi is a embedded  system, so basically not reliable for a server

Comment: What happens if you do `select *  from my_table where id > 12470 AND id < 12480` for example

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Same problem here when looking for multiple rows when id=12471 is included in the range. I agree that a raspi is not reliable at all, I am using it just for local testing.

Comment: @nbk Your query is not working too.

Comment: I think you have a physical corruption in the file

Comment: then check the file system for corruption, also run mysqlcheck